# Measuring Reflow and Paint times in WebKit

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, profiling, reflow

I'm designing a JavaScript/HTML-driven user interface on embedded hardware with weak CPU and WebKit.

Performance is not ideal, and I want to profile the application, especially timing the reflow and repaint events to get hard data on actual performance rather than subjective and changing opinions.

Timing using the regular "getTime()" before and after doesn't work, since WebKit defers reflow and repaint to after the event handlers.

I've tried profiling the app under Speed Tracer, but the computations are so cheap the reflow-events doesn't even show up on PC hardware. I guess some tool more focused on reflow/repaint might still be useful though.

Any tips on how to get hard data for this?

Comment: I only know of dynatrace ajax edition, but that is IE only, i would be very interested in a tool that could do this as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something like getting the document height forces reflow. Maybe you can combine this with getTime().

For example:

```
var t1, t2;
t1 = new Date().getTime();

// Do some DOM manipulation

// Force reflow
document.body.offsetHeight;

t2 = new Date().getTime();
console.log(t2 - t1);
```

Comment: That can't really be used to profile existing code to find the weak points thats needs optimization

Comment: @Martin, sure it's not a full-blown profiling tool, but you can at least time the reflowing that occurs from existing code (I think), which is what the OP specifically mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think it will get me at least a little bit further. :)

Comment: You can use console.time & console.timeEnd API's so you don't have to manage the timing aspect yourself

Answer (score 2):

These links might be helpful. Someone in JP has found out a way to do a nice visualization of reflow for gecko:
http://blog.mozilla.com/gen/2009/04/09/how-to-make-your-own-gecko-reflow-video/

Unfortunatly, this requires a custom firefox build. Instructions here : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Simple_Firefox_build

Comment: Thank you, but my need is specifically for WebKit, and the reflows AFAIU aren't exactly equal between Gecko and WebKit.

I'm developing for low-powered embedded hardware, so it's crucial to get the timings for the actual renderer in question.